# Javascript toggle (one at a time)

Tags: javascript

Im looking for a simple way to only have one div open at a time. Im using an accordian style vertical navigation and when I click on one, it displays the div below, when I click on another, it does the same. I would like the previous div to hide again when I click on a different nav link.

This is the javascript im using to get it to open and close:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
//-->
</script>
```

Is there something else I can add that will close the div if another is opened?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, this could be very easy.

Comment: Agreed, in fact, not only would it be easy to do this, but jQuery UI has their own accordion: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: with jQuery you can `.hide()` and `.show()` elements, alse you can easily check if element is visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way would be to just keep track of the previously opened element:

```
(function() { // using an IIFE to prevent polluting the global namespace
    var opened_element = null;

    window.toggle_visibility = function(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if (opened_element && opened_element !== e) {
           opened_element.style.display = 'none';
       }
       if(e.style.display == 'block') {
          e.style.display = 'none';
       }
       else {
          e.style.display = 'block';
       }
       opened_element = e;
    };
}());
```

Comment: +1 .. A sleek solution , instead of Iterating over all the div's in question

Comment: @Evan: I thought I could skip the test whether `opened_element` is `null`, but I can't. Fixed the code, it should work now.

Comment: that worked perfectly!! thanks so much! and thank you to everyone that answered.

Comment: this might be asking too much, but Is there a way that when I click on a link inside that opened div and it takes me to a seperate page, for me to be able to click on a button called "Back" that will take me back to the navigation with the save div open so I wont have to click on the navigation again to find where I was??

Comment: @Evan: I don't know how your HTML looks like, but if each div has a title that you click, make the title a link and give each div an ID. The link should reference the corresponding div element, e.g. `<div><a href="#about">About</a><div id="about"></div></div>`. When you click a title, the browser will automatically add `#about` to the URL and thus save it in the history. Do open the right div on page load, you have to extract the hash part from the URL (on page load) and show the div with that ID.

Comment: @Evan: Something like this (although I cannot really demonstrate the whole process because the content is loaded in an iframe): http://jsfiddle.net/fpK7d/.

Answer (score 0):

Give them all the same class. Hide them all by classname and show the one you clicked on with the id passed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to:

- Use CSS to hide all of your DIVs
- When you want to display one; add a
  class to your open div called "active" or whatever
- Then apply css to
  that class with display: block or what ever.

As Jason said in his comment you can do this with jQuery or you can do it without.

jQuery will provide animation support and easier manipulation of classes.

[jQuery Toggle Class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using JQuery, I assume you want a Javascript answer, you can do this by giving your divs some unique classname like "menudiv", then appending something like the following to your function:

```
var menu_divs = document.getElementsByClassName("menudiv");
for ( var i = 0; i < menu_divs.length; i++ ) {
    if ( menu_divs[i] != e )
        menu_divs[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: that sounds like a good way to do it, but what if I already have those divs named with a class to toggle open/close?

Comment: ok so I was mistake, there was no class names, so I added a class name to each of them as menudiv but I'm having no success.