# Javascript (NO JQUERY) Toggle Div

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to toggle multiple divs with an image map. My end goal is to:

1. Start off with all divs hidden
2. Click on a div to toggle and show
3. Click on a different div to show the second div but hide all other divs
4. Click the last div I selected to hide the div

I am very new to Javascript. Literally took me forever just to get an understanding of how to even create a function to toggle. I CAN'T USE JQUERY so please don't offer any solution that requires me to use that library.

```js
function toggle(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id)
  if(x.style.display =='none')
    x.style.display = 'block';
  else x.style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

```html
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" src="https://picsum.photos/349/290" border="0" width="349" height="290" orgWidth="349" orgHeight="290" usemap="#image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2019-03-13-221105">
<area alt="" title="" href="#" onclick="toggle('unit1')" shape="rect" coords="9,164,152,263" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area alt="" title="" href="#" onclick="toggle('unit2')" shape="rect" coords="198,175,328,273" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area alt="" title="" href="#" onclick="toggle('unit3')" shape="rect" coords="55,25,291,132" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" coords="347,288,349,290" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
</map>

<div id="unit1" class="unit1" style="display: none;">
Hello World
</div>

<div id="unit2" class="unit2" style="display: none;">
This is me
</div>

<div id="unit3" class="unit3" style="display: none;">
Goodbye
</div>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the above code does toggle but the divs will just stack upon one another. I need to only be able to show one div at a time.

Comment: toggle a class is so much easier...

Comment: So you need to select all of the other elements and hide them..

Comment: Can't see anything on your snippet

Comment: @MaheerAli I just fixed the snippet. The DIVs are toggled by clicking the hotspots on the image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript toggle (one at a time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596798/javascript-toggle-one-at-a-time)

Comment: Woops. Sorry I just copied and pasted my code and forgot about the links. Thanks for the adjustments @Phil.

Answer (score 1):

You can  achieve that in following steps.

1. You should first have same `class` for all your divs
2. Use `querySelectorAll()` and hide all elements of class
3. Then you toogle the required `id` using Ternary Operator.
4. You should get all `<area>` and use `addEventListener()` instead of `onclick = toggle(...)`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('area[alt]').forEach((a,i) =>
{
   a.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = document.getElementById(`unit${i+1}`)  
    let {display} = x.style
    document.querySelectorAll('.unit').forEach(z => z.style.display = 'none')
    x.style.display = display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   })
})
```

```html
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" src="https://picsum.photos/349/290" border="0" width="349" height="290" orgWidth="349" orgHeight="290" usemap="#image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2019-03-13-221105">
<area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="9,164,152,263" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area alt="" title="" href="#"  shape="rect" coords="198,175,328,273" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area alt="" title="" href="#"  shape="rect" coords="55,25,291,132" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" coords="347,288,349,290" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
</map>

<div id="unit1" class="unit" style="display: none;">
Hello World
</div>

<div id="unit2" class="unit" style="display: none;">
This is me
</div>

<div id="unit3" class="unit" style="display: none;">
Goodbye
</div>
```

Comment: You could also use the selector `'.unit'`, seems simpler

Comment: @Phil I just changed the `class` for that but forgot to do that. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: One extra thing that could improve this is to prevent the default action on the clicks. That would stop it jumping back up to the top of the screen each time you click the map.

Comment: So I see that it's working on here but would you be familiar with why the script doesn't seem to produce on SharePoint?

Comment: @Steven Wong I don't know what is **SharePoint**. Give me link if you want

Comment: @MaheerAli I was referring to Microsoft SharePoint. Unfortunately I can't because it's company restricted... I'm going to assume that some of the functions listed here aren't applicable in SharePoint's default :(

Answer (score 0):

1) `Get` the new status for the unit you clicked .

2) `Set` **display:none** for all units .

3) `Set` the new status for the unit you clicked .

```js
function toggle(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id) ;
  var newStatus = (x.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none' ;
  var units = document.getElementsByClassName('units') ;
  for( var i = 0; i < units.length ; i++ ) 
    units[i].style.display = 'none'
  x.style.display = newStatus ;
}
```

```html
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" src="https://picsum.photos/349/290" border="0" width="349" height="290" orgWidth="349" orgHeight="290" usemap="#image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2019-03-13-221105" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2019-03-13-221105">
<area alt="" title="" href="#" onclick="toggle('unit1')" shape="rect" coords="9,164,152,263" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area alt="" title="" href="#" onclick="toggle('unit2')" shape="rect" coords="198,175,328,273" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area alt="" title="" href="#" onclick="toggle('unit3')" shape="rect" coords="55,25,291,132" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" coords="347,288,349,290" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
</map>

<div id="unit1" class="units unit1" style="display: none;">
Hello World
</div>

<div id="unit2" class="units unit2" style="display: none;">
This is me
</div>

<div id="unit3" class="units unit3" style="display: none;">
Goodbye
</div>
```

Comment: Running this code on this page works but it's not working on my SharePoint site. Might be some sort of compatibility thing...

Comment: You must add class `units` to  other `unit` s .see html code please.